# Question about calculating norm of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let's define the following Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ on the field $\mathbb{C}$:

$$l^2(\mathbb{Z}) = \{ x = (x_n)_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}: \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|x_n|^2 < \infty  \} $$
with the inner product $\langle x,y \rangle = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} x_n \overline y_n$

and let's define a linear operator $T$ on $\ell_2(\mathbb{Z})$ by
$$ T(...,x_{-1},x_0,x_1,...)_n = (...,\frac{x_{-2}+x_{0}}{2},\frac{x_{-1}+x_{1}}{2},\frac{x_{0}+x_{2}}{2},...)$$
(namely, $x_n \rightarrow \frac{x_{n-1} + x_{n+1}}{2}).$

I would like to compute the norm of this operator.

I started by noticing that we can write

$$T = \frac{1}{2} S^{+} + \frac{1}{2} S^- $$
where $S^+$ and $S^-$ are left and right shifts respectively. Since on this space shifting a sequence doesn't change the value of its norm (since we have infinite amount of elements for all integers) hence $\lVert S^+ (x) \rVert = \lVert x \rVert$ so
$$\lVert T \rVert = \frac{1}{2}\lVert S^+ + S^- \rVert \leq \frac{1}{2} [\lVert S^+ \rVert + \lVert S^- \rVert] = 1.$$

Now I'm unfortunately stuck with the other bound. Using the fact that space is Hilbert I computed
\begin{align}
\lVert Tx \rVert ^2 &= \frac{1}{4} \langle S^+ + S^-, S^+ + S^-\rangle = \frac{1}{4}\Big[\lVert S^+ \rVert^2 + \lVert S^- \rVert^2 +  \langle S^+,S^- \rangle + \langle S^-,S^+ \rangle \Big] \\
&=\frac{1}{4} \Big[2+ \langle S^+, S^- \rangle + \langle S^-, S^+ \rangle \Big].
\end{align}

So, now I'm looking for an element $x$ in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\lVert x \rVert = 1$ and

$$ \langle S^+ x, S^- x \rangle = 1, $$
that is
$$ \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} x_n \overline{x_{n-2}} = 1 .$$

I was trying to do it with $x$ given by
$$x_n = \Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Big)^n$$
for $n>0$ and $0$ otherwise, so that $\lVert x \rVert = 1$ but then

\begin{align} 
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} x_n \overline{x_{n-2}} &= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \Big[\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Big)^{n-1}+\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Big)^{n+1}\Big]^2 = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^n = \frac{1}{2} \neq 1.
\end{align}

I also did some attempts with similar sequences (for example a sequence with $x_0 = 0$ and $x_{-n} = x_n = (\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}})^n$) but unfortunately I wasn't able to reach 1 with any one them.

Could anyone share an idea which sequence could I consider, or if perhaps my initial estimate of $\lVert T \rVert \leq 1$ is too rough in the first place (or if I've made a mistake somewhere else)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed integer $N$, let $x=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ be the sequence such that $x_n=1$ if $\lvert n\rvert\leqslant N$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $\lVert x\rVert^2=2N+1$. Denoting by $y_n$ the $n$-th element of $Tx$, we get that
$y_n=0$ if $\lvert n\rvert\geqslant N+2$, $y_n=1$ if $\lvert n\rvert \leqslant N-1$  and $ y_{\pm N}=y_{\pm (N+1)}=1/2$ hence $\lVert y\rVert^2$ is of order $2N$. This shows that the norm of $T$ is $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Just a note: I believe there is a typo and it should be $y_n=\frac{1}{2}$ for $n = (N+1), -(N+1)$ and not $(N-1), -(N-1)$.